# Why the high part of physical address structure is defined as signed type?

Tags: c, windows

I see some physical address structure is defined like this:

```
typedef union {
   struct {
       ULONG LowPart;
       LONG HighPart;
   } u;
   LONGLONG QuadPart;
} PHYSICAL_ADDRESS;
```

I don't understand why the high part is defined as signed type... Can anyone give an explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number is signed to make math on it make more sense. If you subtract the address 123 from 456, you expect to get the address 333, right? So if you subtract 456 from 123, you expect to get -333, not 18,446,744,073,709,551,283, right? That's why addresses are signed.

The reason only the high part is signed is that a number only has one sign bit, and it's always the highest (most-significant) bit.

Comment: `LowPart` and `HighPart` are two halves of a 64-bit address.  Treating it as a 64-bit signed integer, there's only one sign bit, and it's in the high part.  In practice, only a tiny fraction of the full 64-bit address space (16 exabytes) is going to be available.\

Comment: Half of the address space are negative... so are they wasted? Why not check which operand is bigger before you do subtraction to ensure the result is positive? Is arithmetic the only reason?

Comment: @solotim: The "negative" ones aren't wasted. The CPU doesn't care if the pointer is "negative" -- it just sees the high bit is set.